# linearlayout/textviews scrollable?

Tags: android

Any easy to make a simple linearlayout with a buncha textviews scrollable? Right now, the last textview gets cut off...

(I don't really wanna use a listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ScrollView

An example here:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/

You can find many more examples using Google.

Comment: Perfect. I started thinking to myself after I posted question, "wait. isnt there a ScrollView?" Thanks a lot!